# Force Image Load on Lazy Load XT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading

Any idea how to **Force Image Load** of **specific** `div` of [Lazy Load XT jQuery plugin](https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt) ?
I mean `data-src=""` image will load automatically after page load **without** page scroll or viewport. 

This plugin only loads images on the following events `load` `orientationchange` `resize` `scroll`.

But cannot find any documentation showing how to achieve this.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="specific">
<img data-src="/images/post-image.jpg">
</div>
```

Note: I cannot manually change img attribute `data-src=""` to `src=""`

Comment: You missed this http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/demo/autoload.htm

Comment: @AdamAzad thanks any suggestion ?

Comment: You can only force elements in viewport to load imo, therefore read the [docs](https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt#advanced-initialization). `$(elements).lazyLoadXT({show: true});` seems to do the trick then.

Comment: any idea for without page scroll or viewport ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a way for Layz Load XT. But I think that is a pretty neat functionality, so I updated my own plugin, [jQuery Lazy](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy), for this. Maybe this helps you too. It's available since version 1.7.4.

Below I made you an example. Just use the public function `force` to load specific elements, ignoring the viewport.

```js
// create lazy instance
var instance = $(".lazy").lazy({
    chainable: false,
    autoDestroy: false,

    // below just for demonstration
    bind: "event",
    appendScroll: null
});

// just for demonstration
$("body")
  .append('<img class="lazy test1" src="" data-src="//dummyimage.com/150x100/&text=1">')
  .append('<img class="lazy test2" src="" data-src="//dummyimage.com/150x100/&text=2">');
instance.addItems(".lazy");

// load only 'img' with class '.test1'
instance.force(".test1");
```

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.lazy/1.7.4/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've added this function to the new version by now. Maybe you want to know. :) @Aariba